# HEV/H.265 videos are not playing using VLC plug-in in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc, hevc

Even after installing `gstreamer0.10-libde265` and `vlc-plugin-libde265` and updating VLC, when I try to play MPEG-4 or Matroska containers with HEVC/H.265 streams VLC automatically stops.

Comment: try this lead about the VLC version in relation to a possibly added ppa
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213958 and not solving your answer but may be of help: mpv is a nice player

Comment: Could you please 1) run `vlc` in a terminal and open a file with a HEVC stream and 2) run something like `avprobe <FILE>` or `mkvinfo-text <FILE>` and include the terminal output of both in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Many vlc issues will be solved by using mc3man's multimedia PPA for Trusty Tahr. First backup your vlc config:

```
mv ~/.config/vlc ~/.config/vlc_bak
```

Then add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This should update your existing packages but to be sure you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-libde265
```

And this should kick start your media playback...